# Breadth First Tree Traversal using Generators in Python

Tags: python-3.x, generator, breadth-first-search, yield-from

I am studying how to use Generators in Python in David Beazly's excellent Python Cookbook text.  The following code recipe defines Depth First Tree Traversal using generators very elegantly:

```
# example.py
#
# Example of depth-first search using a generator

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._children = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node({!r})'.format(self._value)

    def add_child(self, node):
        self._children.append(node)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._children)

    def depth_first(self):
        yield self
        for c in self:
            yield from c.depth_first()

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Node(0)
    child1 = Node(1)
    child2 = Node(2)
    root.add_child(child1)
    root.add_child(child2)
    child1.add_child(Node(3))
    child1.add_child(Node(4))
    child2.add_child(Node(5))

    for ch in root.depth_first():
        print(ch)
    # Outputs: Node(0), Node(1), Node(3), Node(4), Node(2), Node(5)
```

I am trying to come up with an equally elegant method

```
def breadth_first(self):
    pass
```

I am deliberately not posting the crazy stuff that I have been trying since everything that I have tried requires maintaining 'state' within it.  I don't want to use the traditional queue based solutions.  The whole point of this academic exercise is to learn how generators behave in depth.  Therefore, I want to create a parallel 'breadth_first' method using generators for the tree above.

Any pointers/solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use recursion (stack) for `bfs` without some serious hacks, but a queue would work:

```
def breadth_first(self):
    q = [self]
    while q:
        n = q.pop(0)
        yield n
        for c in n._children:
            q.append(c)
```

Comment: I tried your solution.  It works fine :).  I was hoping that I could do it as elegantly as David's depth_first method, but could not.  Oh. well.

Answer (score 0):

The depth first solution you implement is essentially "iterate then recurse"

```
def depth_first(self):
    yield self
    for c in self.children:
        yield from c.depth_first():
```

Inspired by <s>[this blog post](https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2014/02/17/generator/)</s> [the activestate post it references](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/231503-breadth-first-traversal-of-tree/?in=user-218935), you obtain a breadth first search as "recurse then iterate":

```py
def breadth_first(self):
    yield self
    for c in self.breadth_first():
        if not c.children:
            return  # stop the recursion as soon as we hit a leaf
        yield from c.children
```

Edit: it turns out that the linked blog says *"Termination check is absent"*, replaced with an activestate link, which I've adapted to use `yield from` above.

Comment: How do you avoid infinite recursion with `breadth_first`? Seems like it will just keep yielding `self` over and over before complaining about hitting maximum recursion depth.

Comment: If `self` is acyclic (it represents a tree structure), BFS will terminate. You cannot traverse ``up'' in a tree.

Comment: It looks like this does indeed recurse forever after all nodes have been reached...

Comment: I've added the missing termination condition.

Answer (score 0):

I find it both useful and elegant generating the whole breadth, one level at a time. Python 3 generator below:

```
def get_level(t: Node) -> Iterable[List]:
    curr_level = [t] if t else []
    while len(curr_level) > 0:
        yield [node._value for node in curr_level]
        curr_level = [child for parent in curr_level
                            for child in parent._children
                            if child]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if `itertools` had:

```
# zip_chain('ABCD', 'xy') --> A x B y C D
```

It's almost a `itertools.chain(itertools.zip_longest())`, but not quite.

Anyway, `zip_chain` allows:

```
def bf(self):
    yield self
    yield from zip_chain(*map(Node.bf, self.children))
```

It doesn't create a whole row at a time either, I think,